# Remove [restrictions] Tag

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, burninate-request

[restrictions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/restrictions) has 132 questions. A substantial amount of them (at least 28 according to related tags) is about `org.hibernate.criterion.Restrictions`. That could be moved to [hibernate-criteria](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/hibernate-criteria) or become [hibernate-criteria-restrictions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/hibernate-criteria-restrictions).

Comment: But if we remove all the restrictions from the questions... chaos will ensue!!!

Comment: @AndrewBarber we need more kaos!

Comment: @Braiam Good point. Wait... what?

Comment: btw, the title would be more funny if it's "remove the [restrictions]"

Comment: @Braiam Yeah! It happen to me.. At first look at Meta Hot Posts list "I thought it's about removing restrictions", and curiously reached here,but... btw now updated Title.

Comment: Related: the [restrict] tag http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/291664/2799037

Comment: Has been moved to [restrict] tag, which now has a separate burn request. Calling this done as of now.

Answer (score 4):

Using [hibernate-criteria-restrictions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/hibernate-criteria-restrictions) instead is a good idea.

I've searched for such things before and would use such a tag.