# Restrict the use of [restrict]

Tags: discussion, burninate-request

The tag [restrict](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/restrict) has no wiki page or short summary, so it unclear what is meant by the tag. Half of the questions using this tag are in the context of C where `restrict` is a keyword and some C++ support a similar attribute.
The other half of the question use the tag just as a English word without a common technical term in mind.

If you are against deleting the tag, we should define its meaning in the C context and remove the tag from all non-C questions.

Edit:
I propose to delete [restrict](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/restrict) and move legitimate uses (C/C++) to [restrict-qualifier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/restrict-qualifier)

Comment: There is only one follower of the tag. It doesn't seem terribly useful if there is one follower.

Comment: If we decide to keep it, maybe rename it [c-restrict] so people just typing their question title in the tag box won't pick it up?

Comment: restrict-qualifier might be the same thing

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First of all, something should be done about these tags. Yesterday, I failed to find some questions relevant to a problem of mine because they were only tagged [restrict-qualifier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/restrict-qualifier) and the questions from which I took the tag to search only used [restrict](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/restrict) (also the latter is the more populated tag; hence it is offered first).

In their current definitions [restrict](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/restrict) and [restrict-qualifier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/restrict-qualifier) are synonymous, but the former is littered with questions to which the tag does not apply at all.

As to how to solve this issue, I looked at the numbers and the following seems the most easy and least perturbing way:

1. Tag the 33 questions ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/restrict%20c%2b%2b%20-restrict-qualifier), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/restrict+c+-restrict-qualifier)) that are tagged with [restrict](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/restrict) and a main C tag¹ but not tagged with [restrict-qualifier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/restrict-qualifier) with the latter (all of those seem to be tagged correctly).
2. Quickly look through the [259 questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/restrict%20-c%20-c%2b%2b%20-c99) that are tagged [restrict](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/restrict) but are not tagged with a main C tag¹ as to whether any of them should be tagged [restrict-qualifier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/restrict-qualifier) (at a quick glance, I could not find a single such question, so this should be easy and only require few retaggings).
3. Delete the [restrict](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/restrict) tag.

I oppose synonymising [restrict](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/restrict) to [restrict-qualifier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/restrict-qualifier) afterwards, as I do not think that anybody who will need it will fail to find and use the correct tag, once [restrict](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/restrict) is gone, and the latter is prone to be misused (which caused this mess in the first place).

---

¹ [c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c), [c99](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c99), or [c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b)

Comment: If you agree with this, do not forget to upvote the question, as [a score of 20 is required for burnination](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/324070/2127008).

Answer (score -5):

Language designers are very apt to pick common words in English.  Certainly the case for the *restrict* keyword in C and C++, very expressive of what it tries to accomplish.  And a Really Big Deal in those languages, the optimizer pays attention to it with a very unpredictable outcome.  That generates many questions.

Those designers pick common words like *restrict*, without paying attention to SO [tags] or other common usages of the word in natural language.  To help programmers memorize the word, surely you'll understand why.  Words like "for", "if" etcetera were not picked by accident.  And the C and C++ communities know *exactly* what it means.  There might be the occasional lost puppy that does know those languages well enough and uses [restrict] inappropriately.  Pretty uncommon and such questions never last for very long.  That vast majority of questions asked there that have the tag in fact ask about the keyword.

The fact that *other* programmers that know beans about C or C++ like to use that word as well is not their problem. It is not our problem.  They are asking question in English and use English tags.  They are not asking a question about C or C++.

And questioners always know how to make this obvious.  They never fail to *also* tag their question with [c] or [c++].  Increasing the odds that they'll get an answer because many C and C++ programmers also know something about [restrict].

So, is there any point at all in preventing C and C++ programmers asking about the keyword?  What exactly would the alternative tag look like?  Is it *their* fault that other SO users use the tag inappropriately?  Does it make sense to create the [c-restrict] *and* the [c++-restrict] tags, tags that not a single expert subscribed as favorite in their profile?

Of course not.

If it bugs you then cleanup the tag.

Comment: What about synonyms?

Comment: Propose one.  Good luck.

Comment: Most seem not to be about C or C++, but someone trying to enter their whole question as tags. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/restrict%20-c%20-c%2b%2b Not sure whether it's an argument for or against. (The only possible synonym I see would be restrict to restrict-qualifier, though not sure that's a good idea even after a possible cleanup.)

Comment: After further consideration, adding a synonym would add insult to injury: All questions about the restrict-qualifier already have that tag (Added it to about 15), and the bog in [restrict] should not be allowed to pollute that.

Comment: What's the use case for [restrict] beside C/C++? Why should a [restrict] tag help non-C/C++ questions? Nobody will look for  [restrict] questions, they rather type the word directly. I don't see any legitimate use of [restrict] that is not covered by using [restrict-qualifier].