# Repeal the [restriction]

Tags: discussion, tags, burninate-request

The tag [restriction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/restriction) seems to be useless:

1. **Does it describe the contents of the questions to which it is applied?** and **is it unambiguous?**
   Not really.  Most of the questions are either "How can I do X even though it looks like I can't do X?" or "How can I stop other people from doing X?" But that just as easily describes about 80% of all good questions on Stack Overflow. We also have a few about Hibernate restrictions and other such things.
2. **Is the concept described even on-topic for the site?**
   To the extent that it is a topic, I suppose so. But it's really vague. I don't think you can be an expert in "restriction."
3. **Does the tag add any meaningful information to the post?**
   Not in most cases. It's either already in the title/body, or it's otherwise superfluous.
4. **Does it mean the same thing in all common contexts?**
   No.  Some questions are about things *called* restrictions, for instance, while others are about various "restrictions" which questioners have run into or want to implement.

There was a [previous discussion](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/262157/remove-restrictions-tag) on [restrictions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/restrictions), which is apparently back from the dead.

Comment: Related: the [restrict] tag http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/291664/2799037

Answer (score 1):

The tag wiki says:

> A restriction is anything that constrains or limits the code in some fashion.

Well, that's useless for describing Stack Overflow questions, and it doesn't even apply to a large proportion of questions with this tag: they are typically about how to restrict the input, the output, the user, or so on, not about restrictions on the code itself (beyond the trivial way in which all software requirements are "restrictions" on code which is supposed to meet those requirements).

As of 25th October 2022, the tag has 686 questions about a huge range of different topics, and only 10 watchers (who are, presumably, not experts in all of those various topics). The tag should be removed.